# Indian rose drink rose name

Tags: roses

What is the technical (latin and common) name for the perfumed roses used to make Indian rose drinks? Is there one type our several ? I would like to get a few and plant them in my garden. Thanks.

Comment: In my (far from India) experience, the lassi (or whatever else - works well in lemonade, too) has a bit of rose water (commercial packaged product) added to it. Presumably that then makes your question what types of roses go into rose water (and the additional question of "is "Rose water" == "Rose essence" or not...) I just buy a bottle of rose water every few years and don't worry about it too much. Look for the stuff meant to be food, of course. In seeking roses, you'll want ones with the now out of fashion "smells like a rose" characteristic.

Answer (score 4):

This [site](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/rose+essence) says rose essence can be used for the drink.  Rose essence is made from "centifolia, damascena and gallic (rose variants)"

So, this leads to  Rosa × centifolia,Rosa × damascena, and Rosa gallica

Comment: Thank you, I will see off I can find these at my local flower shop. Where on the site is it reference that those are the roses from which the Indian drink I mentioned are made? Thanks.

Comment: This page says rose essence is used to make the drink http://secretindianrecipe.com/recipe/gulab-sherbat-rose-drink

Comment: I'm a bit blind and couldn't find it. Do you know the Indian name for the rose drink? Also, could you include a picture of the drink to make sure we're talking about the same thing. That would help clarify. Thanks.